# Check the blob(image) is existing or not using mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I get the blob data from mysql.
And how to check the blob data is existing or not using php.

```
if (image exists)
{
  #Do some operation
}
else
{
  #Do some operation
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just compare if fetched blob column is not null ?

```
if ( !empty( $row['blob_column'] ) ) {

}
```